# sudoedit non interactive with password and editor input from script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

(I'm a beginner in linux and shell)

I need to run a sudoedit -u from a non interactive bash script
I have the password in a variable and the input for the editor
My challenge is to give password AND editor inputs to sudoedit

For the context, I need to make a kind of automatic unit tests for sudoers commands.
So my actual strategy is to run the main script with a user A. In that script I need to switch to a second user B (su) to run a subscript that run the sudoedit command (sudoedit -u userC). And I need to get the $? of the sudoedit for my main script report.

I have tested many things without success. Is there a way to give both password and editor input ? (Or an other way to perform what I need to do ?)

I tried that :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# master script
userB=userB
userBpassword=xxx
export userBpassword
su - userB bash child.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < <(echo $userBpassword)
isSuccess=$? # I need the information of success or not for file edition
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudoedit -u userC file.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 < <(echo ":wq") # I must inject userBpassword here but how ?
return $?
```

I must do that non interactive (just asking logins and passwords once at start)
Ideally I should have 0 if sudoedit is success or anithing else if there is a failure (no right or missing file)

Thanks in advance for reading and help

Comment: You should look into configuring `sudo` (via the `sudoers` file) to run the necessary commands without any password.

Comment: What is the `sudoedit` command for? You appear to be trying to exit as soon as it starts (and assuming that `sudoedit` will be executing some version of `vi` seems naïve).